I'd like some help using midjourney-proxy-plus
I'd like some help using midjourney-proxy-plus.
I looked up several GitHub repositories to automate midjourney use. I succeeded in using midjourney-proxy, but failed to use midjourney-proxy-plus.
This site tells me to download app.jar but I couldn't find any mention of where I could get it. If anyone has tried this feature, I'd appreciate it if you could help.

The Readme says you need to contact them to get the app, there is a WeChat QR code for that in the Readme.
